# ¿Cómo validar formulario con un estado de objetos en reactjs?

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

intento validar mi formulario y he establecido en una constante dos valores: valor y ok. cuando ok este en true entonces el estado de error TextField se pasará en true. hasta ahí bien.

**el problema esta en que me falla el OnChange**
quiero extraer el valor de name y de email y me falla.
en que me estoy equivocando?
por cierto si name y email solo tuvieran un string funciona bien. ej: name: "", email "" pero eso no quiero.

```
const [form, setForm] = useState({
name: {
  valor: "nombre completo",
  ok: false
},
email: {
  valor: "email@ooo.com",
  ok: false
}});


const onChange = ({ target }) => {
    const { name, value } = target;

    setForm({
      ...form,
      [name]: value
    });
  };
```

mi TextField son los siguientes

```
<TextField
      name="name"
      value={form.name.valor}
      onChange={onChange}
      error={form.name.ok}
    />
    <TextField
      name="email"
      value={form.email.valor}
      onChange={onChange}
      error={form.email.ok}
    />
```

Comment: Estas reemplazando los objetos de tu estado con el valor que escribes en cada input, por eso las propiedades _valor_ y _ok_ no se visualizan.

Comment: ok, entiendo, pero como no tengo idea como modificar el onChange. échame una mano diciendo que agrego o como lo agrego para enlazarlo

Answer (score 1, accepted):

La implementación de tu `onChange`, debe enfocarse en que para asignar el valor del input al campo valor de tu objeto **name** o **email**, debes ir navegando por los niveles correspondientes, ya que al indicarle `[event.target.name]: event.target.value`, automáticamente estás reemplazando un `Object` por un `String`.

Aclarado esto, mi solución sería

```
const onChange = (event) => {
   const { target } = event;

   setForm({
      ...form,
      [target.name]: { valor: target.value, ok: form[target.name].ok }
   });
};
```

Donde al *target.name*, le asignamos el objeto con la misma estructura que tiene tu `state`.

Nos comentas que tal te va o si tienes alguna duda :D